# Filament add ambient light without IBL

Tags: webgl, google-filament

I am trying to render a model with a ambient light added to the scene, however I didn't find any documentation about it..

Answer (score 0):

Use white screen hdr image and generate ibl file with cmgen.exe to make the object bright as possible!
You can do lots of things with it!
Photoshop can edit hdr, exr and ... formats!